# How can I set the MySQL’s password in the “mysqld_safe” is running scenario?

Tags: mysql, macos

I use bellow command find the running `mysql` service:

```
$ps -ef | grep mysqld
  501  4512     1   0 12:19 pm ??         0:00.06 /bin/sh /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe --port=8889 --socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock --pid-file=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid --log-error=/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log
  501  4849  4512   0 12:19 pm ??         0:00.29 /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld --basedir=/Applications/MAMP/Library --datadir=/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql56 --plugin-dir=/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/plugin --log-error=/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log.err --pid-file=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid --socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock --port=8889
```

But I forget the password, or maybe I did not set it.

How can I set my MySQL’s password?

And whether the `mysqld_safe` service is running means the password did not set?

Comment: `mysqld_safe` is a overengineered service availability script that has nothing to do with passwords.

Comment: [A few ways to reset passwords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html) (adjust for the right mysql version).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Stop the MySQL demon process using this command :

   ```bash
   sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
   ```
2. Start the `mysqld` daemon process using the `--skip-grant-tables` option with this command:

   ```bash
   sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
   ```
3. Start the MySQL client process using this command:

   ```bash
   mysql -u root
   ```
4. From the MySQL prompt execute this command to be able to change any password

   ```sql
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
   ```
5. Then reset/update your password

   ```sql
   SET PASSWORD FOR root@'localhost' = PASSWORD('password');
   ```
6. If you have a MySQL root account that can connect from everywhere, you should also do:

   ```bash
   UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('newpwd') WHERE User='root';
   ```
7. Alternate Method:

   ```sql
   USE mysql
      UPDATE user SET Password = PASSWORD('newpwd')
      WHERE Host = 'localhost' AND User = 'root';
   ```
8. And if you have a `root` account that can access from everywhere:

   ```sql
   USE mysql
      UPDATE user SET Password = PASSWORD('newpwd')
      WHERE Host = '%' AND User = 'root';
   ```

   For either method, once have received a message indicating a successful query (one or more rows affected), flush privileges:

   ```sql
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
   ```
9. Then stop the `mysqld` process and relaunch it with the classical way:

   ```bash
   sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
   sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
   ```