# I Didn't Get Option To Set Root Password Of Mysql During Installation

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I didn't get option to set root password of mysql during installation. Now, I am unable to form instance I am beginner in mysql I have tried reinstallating the software watching youtube still didn't got that option.

Comment: please read this page, I wrote before. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52867030/how-can-i-set-the-mysqls-password-in-the-mysqld-safe-is-running-scenario/52868910#52868910

Comment: try this link  [mysql client ] (https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQLInstaller/mysql-installer-community-8.0.19.0.msi)        because workbench is different than mysql client

Answer (score 1):

Actually I had solved this problem the day after posting this question.. My main problem was I was not getting wizard for saving information regarding root password port and etc. I figured after installing quite a few time that I have been clicking on update before the actual product installation as that was first question before installing... Not having previous verison of mysql I was unable to get root wizard i.e I was able to install product but while create database or server I was having trouble with password because it was not set while installation process... Clicking on no before installation for update solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful if you have installed mySql community server.

Download MySQL Installer from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/8.0.html) if you haven't already, then open the installer and you might see some products listed in the section, then click on reconfigure of mySQL Server, it will take you through the instructions of setting up few things including your password(which you'll probably find after clicking "next" a few windows).

[image]