# Can't change root pw in mysql

Tags: mysql

When I try to change the root pw in mysql with `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'myPassword';`, I got the error message:

> Storage engine 'MyISAM' does not support system tables.

So I used

```
alter table mysql.db ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

and

```
alter table mysql.columns_priv ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

as mentioned [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54292491/how-to-fix-error-1726-hy000-storage-engine-myisam-does-not-support-system-t)

Now I get the error

> Cannot load from mysql.db. The table is probably corrupted

And `repair table mysql.db` can't fix it, cause the storage engine for the table doesn't support repair.

Comment: Which version of mysql are you using?

Comment: @MarcoDallaSanta I'm using version 8.0.22 on Ubuntu.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52867030/how-can-i-set-the-mysqls-password-in-the-mysqld-safe-is-running-scenario/52868910#52868910, use this link and don't forget to give upvote.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just removed and re-installed mysql server.
It's not a nice solution but it worked.